# Add HTML element in radio_buttons with Rails and SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

For my project, i tried to insert an HTML element in the `span` block with the `radio` class generated by SimpleForm (cf example of my code below). But after many tests and research, i'm not arrived to insert this element.

I need this HTML element for add gradient border to my radio button checkmark.

In my form, i have this line to generate radio_buttons :

```
<%= f.input :gender, as: :radio_buttons, wrapper: :custom_radio_buttons, collection: [['female', '0'], ['male', '1']] %>
```

In my initializers, i have this block for my custom wrapper :

```
config.wrappers :custom_radio_buttons, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|                                                                                               
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly                                                                                                                                                                                

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'radio-buttons' do |ba|                                                                                                                                              
    ba.use :label_input
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                 

  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }                                                                                                                                       
  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
end
```

This generated the following HTML block :

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional"> 
  <div class="radio-buttons">
    <label class="radio_buttons optional">
      Gender
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="">
    <span class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="0" name="gender" id="gender_0">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="gender_0">
        female
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="1" name="gender" id="gender_1">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="gender_1">
        male
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i insert this element to the `<span class="radio">` blocks generated by SimpleForm ?

Thanks in advance.